# merge two networks in R igraph ggnet2

Tags: r, igraph, ggnetwork

I need to join two network graphs in R, just overposing the second on the first.

I share with you more detalis:
My first graph is a maximum spanning tree in this form:

```
g1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m4, mode = "upper", weighted = T, diag = F)
max_spann_tree2 <- mst(g1, weights = -E(g)$weight)

max_spann_tree2<-asNetwork(max_spann_tree2)
ggnet2(max_spann_tree2 ,size =  nlav1,size.cut = 4, edge.size = 1, edge.color = "grey", color = "he1", color.legend = "industry", palette = "Set3")
```

max_spann_tree2 has this structure:

```
 > max_spann_tree2
     Network attributes:
      vertices = 181 
      directed = FALSE 
      hyper = FALSE 
      loops = FALSE 
      multiple = FALSE 
      bipartite = FALSE 
      total edges= 180 
        missing edges= 0 
        non-missing edges= 180 

 Vertex attribute names: 
    he1 vertex.names
```

and I need to overpose this graph

```
net55<-asNetwork(net5)
ggnet2(net55 ,size =  nlav5,size.cut = 4, edge.size = 1, edge.color = "grey", color = "he5", color.legend = "industry", palette = "Set3")
```

net5 has the following structure:

```
> net5

IGRAPH 3893673 UNW- 87 250 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), he (v/c), nlav (v/n), ateco (v/c), weight (e/n)
+ edges from 3893673 (vertex names):
 [1] A1013--A1621 A1039--A1051 A1039--A1089 A1041--A1051 A1041--A1061 A1041--A1071 A1041--A1073 A1041--A2312
 [9] A1041--A2369 A1041--A2370 A1041--A2512 A1041--A6910 A1041--A6920 A1041--A7112 A1051--A2512 A1051--A7420
+ ... omitted several edges
```

I tried with uniongraph without success. Any suggestions to merge this two plot? Can I merge directly the two ggnet2 plot? Or should I do something else?
thanks in advance

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by "overpose". Do you just want the two graphs added as separate pieces? What didn't work with union?

Comment: I mean to merge the two graphs: the first as a base and the second added on. The number of verteces diverges between the two: The first is a maximum spanning tree and the second is a network with the highest value, please see http://science.sciencemag.org/content/sci/suppl/2007/07/26/317.5837.482.DC1/Hidalgo.SOM.pdf        pag 6-7

Comment: You do not provide either graph or explain why union is not what you want. The other thing I think that you might want is `max_spann_tree2  + net5`

Comment: Union does not work for my case. I got an error. Yes max_spann_tree2 + net5 could be the solution. I tried it, but I was not able to plot the graph. What do you suggest me?

Comment: I do not have your data, but if I generate two graphs `g1` and `g2` I can write `g3 = g1 + g2` and then plot `g3`

Comment: I tried as you suggest and I got  `Error:Don't know how to add o to a plot`

Comment: I tried also `elephant1<- graph.union(gephard2,lion2)
Error in .igraph.graph.union.or.intersection("union", ..., byname = byname,  : 
  Not a graph object`                    AND                                                                            `elephant1<- intersection(gephard2,lion2)
Error in UseMethod("intersection") : 
  no applicable method for 'intersection' applied to an object of class "c('gg', 'ggplot')"`